# How to download yaml as it is on linux box using python

Tags: python, yaml

I have yaml file ex:http://server:1234/test.yaml WebUrl
When I download the file with below code on Linux box, its became HTML file, But I need an exact replica of yaml file.

```
import urllib
urllib.urlretrieve('http://server:1234/test.yaml','downloaded.yaml')
```

but the downloaded.yaml file in HTML format rather a yaml file.

how to download same as yaml?

Comment: What happens when you point a browser at that URL and 'view source'?  Does it show HTML?  If so, you need to configure your webserver not to wrap the file in HTML.

Comment: you are correct it wraps to HTML when you look at the source code, but how would I download/read same as yaml format? or is there any way to converts to yaml format from HTML, didn't find any modules in python.

Answer (score 0):

You can either try and persuade the webserver to serve it as plain text (application/x-yaml, text/x-yaml), or you will have to parse the HTML to extract the yaml.

The latter will be painful, because things like `&` and `<` which are not special to yaml, will be escaped in the HTML.  There are plenty of libraries to help parse HTML (but a request for which one to use is explicitly off-topic on Stack Overflow).

If you have any influence over the webserver, I would strongly recommend trying to make it serve the file as text.